# Can't Validate Model Result

Tags: classification, cart, feature-engineering

This is my first question and I am still new to data science and statistics, so please forgive me if this is a dumb or ill-posed question. I have two ensemble tree classifier models built on the same set of about 40 mixed continuous/categorical features - one a random forest, the other an XGB model. Both models rank a particular continuous feature (call it X1) very highly on the feature importances list; but when I look at X1 vs. Y, or any plausible X1 vs. X2 I can think of, I can't see any separation or pattern in the classes. I also don't see strong correlation/association between X1 and any other features. In other words, I don't understand why the models select this feature as important, and thus how I can use this insight to help take action based on the model. The other features the models select do suggest some interesting actions, but this one does not.

I will work on non-tree-based models to see if they also select X1, but in general, do you have any advice for how to handle situations like these? What should I do next, to investigate and validate what the model says is important? Thanks in advance for any advice to a newbie.

Comment: Hi there and welcome. 1) Please provide more context: what kind of variables are we talking about? 2) Here's an idea: run the exact same analysis with `X1` removed from the training set.

Comment: Why is classification importantant to you vs. prediction?  See [this](http://fharrell.com/post/classification).  I think that what you are trying to do requires a significant amount of study before analyzing the data.

Comment: Hi Jim and Frank, and thanks. Sorry for the slow turnaround, I am in Asia. To answer your questions, I am trying to model final test failure in a manufactured product, so it's a binary pass/fail classification situation. As you might have guessed, fails are the minority class by a big margin, so I have down-sampled the passers to balance the classes. Even so, this is high-volume manufacturing, so I still have several thousand failures in each dataset.

Comment: Sorry, new to this and didn't understanding editing time limit. To finish: the features are both categorical (e.g. type of fixture used) and numerical (e.g. yields at various operations). The X1 feature is the number of prior uses of the test fixture, i.e. very plausible. When I remove it, the other 2 key features just take its place and the model accuracy remains high...

Comment: Frank, thanks also, and interesting article! As you see above, I am guilty of down-sampling! I do, however, base my classification on the probabilities from each model in the ensemble, and adjust the decision threshold near the optimal F1 score, with some bias toward recall over precision to reflect business need (i.e. the relative costs of over- and under-rejecting). When done, I will use the model only to flag certain parts for special testing, rather than scrap them, so it's similar to what your article describes. Still, perhaps logistic regression, SVM, or something else would be better?

Comment: In case anyone reads this, I discovered the problem: my fixture age feature had so much float precision that the model was using it as a proxy for choosing individual fixtures within each dataset. So I was correct that there was no general relationship between fixture age and test failure; in truth there was only a non-repeatable association between fixture ID and failure rate in any individual dataset. In short, the problem was a flexible tree model with insufficient binning. Proper binning prevented age being used as a proxy and resolved the problem. Thanks Jim and Frank for trying to help!